# How can we view all the options/values available in the select dropdown without scroll bar (JSP)?

Tags: css, jsp

Could you please help me in viewing all the values/options available in select dropdown without scrollbar?
using size attribute is not matching my UseCase as the output/dropdown comes more like a textarea.

```
<select name="test" id="test1" value=<reading from another property file> class="modify" style="width:220px" />
```

inside css file:

```
select.modify{
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Manipulating native DOM elements is not possible without using some javascript, what I suggest is to override the UI of your HTML element with combination of CSS, HTML, and Javascript like the following snippet:

```js
var x, i, j, selElmnt, a, b, c;
/* Look for any elements with the class "custom-select": */
x = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-select");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  selElmnt = x[i].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
  /* For each element, create a new DIV that will act as the selected item: */
  a = document.createElement("DIV");
  a.setAttribute("class", "select-selected");
  a.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
  x[i].appendChild(a);
  /* For each element, create a new DIV that will contain the option list: */
  b = document.createElement("DIV");
  b.setAttribute("class", "select-items select-hide");
  for (j = 1; j < selElmnt.length; j++) {
    /* For each option in the original select element,
    create a new DIV that will act as an option item: */
    c = document.createElement("DIV");
    c.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[j].innerHTML;
    c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        /* When an item is clicked, update the original select box,
        and the selected item: */
        var y, i, k, s, h;
        s = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
        h = this.parentNode.previousSibling;
        for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
          if (s.options[i].innerHTML == this.innerHTML) {
            s.selectedIndex = i;
            h.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
            y = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("same-as-selected");
            for (k = 0; k < y.length; k++) {
              y[k].removeAttribute("class");
            }
            this.setAttribute("class", "same-as-selected");
            break;
          }
        }
        h.click();
    });
    b.appendChild(c);
  }
  x[i].appendChild(b);
  a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    /* When the select box is clicked, close any other select boxes,
    and open/close the current select box: */
    e.stopPropagation();
    closeAllSelect(this);
    this.nextSibling.classList.toggle("select-hide");
    this.classList.toggle("select-arrow-active");
  });
}

function closeAllSelect(elmnt) {
  /* A function that will close all select boxes in the document,
  except the current select box: */
  var x, y, i, arrNo = [];
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("select-items");
  y = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected");
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    if (elmnt == y[i]) {
      arrNo.push(i)
    } else {
      y[i].classList.remove("select-arrow-active");
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (arrNo.indexOf(i)) {
      x[i].classList.add("select-hide");
    }
  }
}

/* If the user clicks anywhere outside the select box,
then close all select boxes: */
document.addEventListener("click", closeAllSelect);
```

```css
/* The container must be positioned relative: */
.custom-select {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.custom-select select {
  display: none; /*hide original SELECT element: */
}

.select-selected {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

/* Style the arrow inside the select element: */
.select-selected:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 14px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
}

/* Point the arrow upwards when the select box is open (active): */
.select-selected.select-arrow-active:after {
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
  top: 7px;
}

/* style the items (options), including the selected item: */
.select-items div,.select-selected {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Style items (options): */
.select-items {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}

/* Hide the items when the select box is closed: */
.select-hide {
  display: none;
}

.select-items div:hover, .same-as-selected {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<!-- Surround the select box within a "custom-select" DIV element.
Remember to set the width: -->
<div class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
  <select>
    <option value="0">Select car:</option>
    <option value="1">Audi</option>
    <option value="2">BMW</option>
    <option value="3">Citroen</option>
    <option value="4">Ford</option>
    <option value="5">Honda</option>
    <option value="6">Jaguar</option>
    <option value="7">Land Rover</option>
    <option value="8">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="9">Mini</option>
    <option value="10">Nissan</option>
    <option value="11">Toyota</option>
    <option value="12">Volvo</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

This gives you flexibility and allow you to control your HTML elements style and how they look, this example still might not work right ahead for you but, with some changes you can have full control over the size and width of your HTML select element

reference: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp